# How to download 3000 files from a website?

Tags: automation

I would like to download about 3000 files of about 500kb size each.
They are in a website that needs login.
Doing it manually needs 5 clicks each.
Is there a way to aumatize it?
They have a pattern in names.

Comment: If you Google it, you’ll find tutorials that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the login is straightforward and there isn't javascript in the page, it is very simple to do using Python.  You can google for web scraping with Python, then for downloading files with Python.   I wrote a short program to do this for a couple sites.

Answer (score 0):

The Chrome and Firefox add-on stores both have an abundance of free *web spider* add-ons, and they're probably the fastest to configure.
Some sophisticated download manager add-ons provide this functionality as well, such as GetRight Download Manager & FreeDownload Manager (if that one still exists).

This can also be achieved using dedicated spider tools - both installable and web-based varieties exist.

You can execute wget from bash and batch scripts if you'd like to develop your own solution using the naming pattern.

I'm sorry I need to run, but there *are* lots of options available like these, and I'll be able to give more detail when I have my break